# Does a table like user_tables (used in oracle) in db2 exist?

Tags: database, db2, db2-luw

I know that `syscat.tables` exists in db2. 
I also tried to find the count in `user_tables` and I got the output this way:

```
db2 =>  select count(*) from user_tables

1
-----------
        999

  1 record(s) selected.
```

but I couldn't describe the table `user_tables` while I could describe any other table.

Example:

```
db2 => describe table user_tables

                                Data type                     Column
Column name                     schema    Data type name      Length     Scale Nulls
------------------------------- --------- ------------------- ---------- ----- ------

  0 record(s) selected.

SQL0100W  No row was found for FETCH, UPDATE or DELETE; or the result of a
query is an empty table.  SQLSTATE=02000
```

Could you help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve and correct your spelling.

Comment: I formatted the code of your, question. Please also try your best to write using correct grammar and style to make it easy to read your question.

Comment: Try specifying the schema: `describe table sysibmadm.user_tables`

Comment: @mustaccio : thank u so much :) ..it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 has an [Oracle compatibility mode](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/c_compat_oracle.html) which needs to be enabled for a database. As part of this users can opt to have [Oracle data dictionary-compatible views](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/c0054440.html) created. One of the views is `user_tables`.

Could you try the following (not tested):

```
describe select * from user_tables
```

This should return the schema for the result table which is that view.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM systables WHERE SYSTEM_TABLE_SCHEMA ='YOURSCHEMA'